# Console Starting Menu

Tags: c#

```
 public  static int Menu() // 1 - Start Game , 2 - Quit Game
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Console.WriteLine("Rock - Paper - Scissors");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine("_______________________");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("- Start Game");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine("- Quit Game");
        ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
        keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            return 1; // Start Game
        }
        else
        {
            if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.WriteLine("Rock - Paper - Scissors");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine("_______________________");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("- Start Game");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("- Quit Game");
                if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    return 2; // Quit Game
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        return Menu(); // Recursion :)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return 2;
    }
```

My problem is the when it reaches "quit game" and I press up arrow I actually need to press 2 times the up arrow for it to work instead of 1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Aside from the answer posted, couple of things here - 1. This is a bad place for recursion as every "game" will add another call to the stack, unnecessarily eating up more and more memory as more games are played . Try a loop instead. 2. `else { if { } }` can be simplified to `else if { }`.

Comment: +1 to moving from recursion :). In a while like this, it will be better to have a variable that stores a key which is dedicated to 'Quit'. 1. Display the welcome screen. 2. Read a key from the user (and store in a variable!). 3. If it is the quit key, prompt/quit. Else, enter a loop which has is dependent on whether the **last** key pressed was the quit key or not. I can flesh it out more if that will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you call `ReadKey` every time the `if` conditions are evaluated. Instead, store the result in a variable.

```
var key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
if (key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
{
    Console.Clear();
    return 2; // Quit Game
}
else
{
    if (key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        return Menu(); // Recursion :)
    }
}
```

This way, you will call `ReadKey` only once and your first <kbd>↑</kbd> will be considered.

In the current state of your code, you could have pressed any key that isn't <kbd>Enter</kbd> the first time and still read the second if that checks for <kbd>↑</kbd>.

```
// ReadKey is called for the first time...
if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
{
    Console.Clear();
    return 2; // Quit Game
}
else // ...if it wasn't Enter...
{
    // ...ReadKey is called a second time.
    if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        return Menu(); // Recursion :)
    }
}
```